# has-error class not attaching to .form-group div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, validation

I have the next `.form-group` divs in my form:

```
<div class="form-group" style="border-bottom:0">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Contacto Principal</label>
    <div class='col-md-3'>
        <input type='text' id='nombreContactoVenta' name='nombreContactoVenta' class='form-control' placeholder='Ej: Pedro'>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-3'>
        <input type='text' id='apellidoContactoVenta' name='apellidoContactoVenta' class='form-control' placeholder='Ej: Ramirez'>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class='col-md-3 col-md-offset-4'>
        <input type='text' id='telefonoContactoVenta' name='telefonoContactoVenta' class='form-control' placeholder='Ej: 011 65098752'>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-3'>
        <input type='text' id='emailContactoVenta' name='emailContactoVenta' class='form-control' placeholder='Ej: email@ejemplo.com'>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the validation code:

```
errorPlacement: function(error, e) {
    e.parents('.form-group > div').append(error);
},
highlight: function(e) {
    $(e).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success has-error').addClass('has-error');
    $(e).closest('.help-block').remove();
},
success: function(e) {
    // You can use the following if you would like to highlight with green color the input after successful validation!
    e.closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success has-error'); // e.closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success has-error').addClass('has-success');
    e.closest('.help-block').remove();
}
```

The thing is, `nombreContactoVenta` and `telefonoContactoVenta` are required, but, when I submit, the only `.form-group` that gets the `.has-error` class is the one that contains `nombreContactoVenta`. Both get the `.help-block` div, but only one the class, unless I click the input. If I click the "gray" input, it, somehow, gets the class. What drives me crazy is that I cannot see any difference between this inputs.

Here is a print.

[The "gray" input changes when I click it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDGUS.png)

There is something else, I don't know if it's important, but I don't know so many things. The required method is conditional for both of the inputs.

```
nombreContactoVenta: {
    required: function() {
        if($("#apellidoContactoVenta").val() || $("#emailContactoVenta").val() || $("#telefonoContactoVenta").val())
        {
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }
},
telefonoContactoVenta: {
    required: function() {
        if($("#apellidoContactoVenta").val() || $("#emailContactoVenta").val() || $("#nombreContactoVenta").val())
        {
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }
}
```

Thanks!